# How to switch regex processing in TextChanged event for input string after specific word

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq, textbox

I have several replace and regex filters before pass string to process, something like this:

```
 string inputText = (textBox1.Text);
 string outputText = Regex.Replace(inputText, @"(?<=\W)(?<! )\W+", " ");
```

but before pass it to `inputText` in `private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` event, I have initial regex filters, with separate string filtering process during the typing, allows only lowercase, specific marks etc.

And I want create some special word for example "break" and at the stage of typing into the textbox, I want to get processing of my `textBox1_TextChanged` active, until specific word "break" wasn't inputted, then text must become without any processing of any given filters.

To make it clear as example, if string written by user is:

> Hello, world!!! How are You? I'm ok.

and `textBox1_TextChanged` event processing changes it into:

> hello world how are you i m ok

in case of typing of word "break" inside textbox, string must be:

> hello world how /break/ are You? I'm ok.

and result for further passing to `inputText`:

> hello world how / are You? I'm ok.

to use this word as special border between processed and not processed content in string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search `inputText` for the substring `"break"` using `String.IndexOf()`. If you find it, use the `String.Substring()` method to split the string into two halves: From the beginning until the character before the start of `"break"`, and from the "b" in `"break"` to the end.

If `"break"` isn't found, the second substring should just be an empty string.

Put the first substring through your regex thing. Don't put the other one through it. Concatenate the two.

Your idea of somehow having the event handler fire for only part of the control's text is impossible, and it's the wrong way to think about the problem. The way to think about it is that you have one string, and you want the handler to do different things to two different parts of it.